# QT Multimedia, black screen for H264 movie

Tags: c++, qt, h.264, multimedia

I'm trying to play a movie using the QT Multimedia framework (5.0.1), but I only get a black screen with a mov coded with H.264.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *mainWidget = new QWidget();
    mainWidget->setGeometry(0,0, 1920, 1080);

    QVideoWidget *widget = new QVideoWidget(mainWidget);
    widget->setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080);

    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
    QUrl localUrl = QUrl::fromLocalFile("test_mov.mov");
    player->setMedia(localUrl);
    qDebug() << "Player error state -> " << player->error();
    qDebug() << "Media supported state -> " << QMediaPlayer::hasSupport("video/mov");
    player->setVideoOutput(widget);

    mainWidget->show();

    player->play();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The code compiles correctly and gives the following output on console, while the video widget remains black:

> Player error state ->  QMediaPlayer::NoError
>   Media supported state -> 1 //  means "Probably supported"

I'm using Qt 5.0.1 on a Mac OSX 10.7.5. The file is correctly played by the player and ffmpeg -i test_mov.mov gives

> Duration: 00:00:02.52, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 63708 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 63684 kb/s, SAR 1745:1920 DAR 349:216, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc

Does anyone knows what are the formats supported by QT Multimedia ?

Thank you

Comment: You're checking support for "video/mov" and it's "Probably supported". However, that's just the container. See if you can check for H.264 video codec support. That might be trickier.

Comment: Same result (probably supported) with an mp4 encoded with h264, changing "video/mov" to "video/H264" and the file itself. The command line utility file returns : "file test_h264.mp4" -> "test_h264.mp4: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2"

Comment: About the 'file' command: it isn't able to dig deep enough into a MOV/MP4 file to determine codecs. Back on topic, I don't know if we've established whether the Qt Multimedia framework can access the system H.264 decoder on a Mac OS X platform. Maybe there are other components that need to be in place for this to succeed.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows, QT video file formats usually appear with the .mov filename extension.
 Other file formats that QuickTime supports natively (to varying degrees) include AIFF, WAV, DV, MP3, and MPEG-1.

Comment: I succeded by switching platform, from OS X to Windows. Probably it was a codec problem, as Multimedia Mike previously suggested